# signing the client code

Tags: security, meteor

I would like to make sure that the code which is deployed to the client of my meteor app has not been tampered with.

In order to achieve that, it would be nice to sign the client part and be able to verify that signature on the client prior to execution.

This way, even if someone hacked my server and replaced my app, at least they would not be able to get the users to execute malicious code.

Comment: who is checking the signature? the client? the same client code that you're worried about being replaced?

Comment: good point. but the checking could be done by a different application. One that does not get updated automatically